# Preferred way to design application arhitecture in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, architecture

I have application which has `MainWindow` that is divided in three main parts:

[image]

Thing is, all three parts need to communicate between themselves. For example, there is a `QListView` in left section where you select items, and depending on the selected item options change in the right section.

I have come up with three solutions:

1. draw everything within the `MainWindow` which would make `MainWindow` one big superclass:

This solution solves all problems with communication between widgets because all of them are part of `MainWindow::ui` but then I get one big (potentially messy) class.

2. put each section in it's own class and make `MainWindow` a singleton:

This solution is... well a singleton. And I don't really like singletons. I will have access to `MainWindow` from everywhere (essentially I am creating a global variable) and I would still have to expose `MainWindow::ui` (and `::ui`s of other sections) via getter which would mean that everything will have access to `::ui`s.

3. put each section in it's own class and connect everything via signals and slots:

This would probably be the best solution but with this solution I need to create getter for each widget from `EachSection::ui` (to be able to connect it in `MainWindow` with it's counterparts), I would need a lot of calls to `connect()` and I also have a problem if two slots react to same signal but they need to react in specific order.

So what would be the best approach?

Comment: A bit opinion-based question. Anyway, you should divide your UI elements by their purpose, so if you think that there are many elements that belong directly to `MainWindow`, just put all of them in the `MainWindow` UI. In QT it is easy to access the children objects by call to `myObj->findChild<QWhatever*>()`. If some part of your `MainWindow` is a complex widget with it's own specific behavior, just make it a separate class and put one or more instances of this class in your `MainWinow` UI.

Comment: I suggest to edit the question and focus it on some specific problem with one of the solutions. My quick guess is that you want approach 1 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to define messaging (protocol) between views, so that views is not tightly coupled (all views isolated and dont know about each other) one instance class (main window) know all three and connects them. Imagine a button line edit and label, when you press button label gets value of line edit, button implementation does not depend on lineedit implementation, lineedit does not depend on label and so on, all three classes can be extended or changed and it doesnot affect two other, so you can focus on one of them at the time.